# Polars calamine engine read xlsx, header row not on row 1

Tags: python, python-polars

I am new to Polars and most of my work has been in Pandas. Polars piqued my interest after discovering that a read operation of around 8 thousand rows on an xlsx file went from almost 7 seconds down to .45 seconds. Main reason I'm seeking to use carmine over the default engine is for the added speed ... default is around 2 seconds. I am seeking to convert an old mothballed pandas script over to Polars but am stuck with getting my header row and data rows first in place.

The problem I'm running into is an xlsx file that contains a formatted report, of which I don't have access to the underlaying data source, and need to extract out the information in this report to be utilized elsewhere.

Looking over the xlsx report, my head row is on line 7 of the XLSX file, and data begins on row 8.
Column A can be ignored as it only contains branding from the report source and some other informational entries unrelated to the actual data.

I've attempted to find a way to select the header or ignore the first 6 rows but have been unsuccessful with discovering a way to do this. ChatGPT is not familiar enough with Calamine or with Polars for me to have successfully found a solution through it.

Below I managed to find a way to isolate the header row into row 1 of header_row but no operations I've attempted so far have been successful in replacing the mostly junk header row currently in df.

I'm hoping to get my header row straightened out, and after doing so, I can do the remaining drop and data manipulations.

## Current State:

```py
# Excel file path
excel_file_path = [File Path]

# Read Excel file
df = pl.read_excel(
    excel_file_path,
    engine="calamine",  # Specify the engine as a string
)

header_row_index = 2
header_row = df.slice(header_row_index)
```

---

Running **print(header_row.head(1))** yields info below.

```
shape: (1, 32)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ Milestone ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ … ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ __UNNAME │
│ Status    ┆ __1       ┆ __2       ┆ __3       ┆   ┆ __30      ┆ __31      ┆ __32      ┆ D__33    │
│ Report    ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ ---       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆   ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str      │
│ str       ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆          │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╡
│ Subdivisi ┆ Job       ┆ Lot       ┆ Template  ┆ … ┆ Ready for ┆ Buyer Ori ┆ Orientati ┆ Buyer    │
│ on        ┆           ┆ Number    ┆           ┆   ┆ Orienatio ┆ entation  ┆ on Accept ┆ Closed   │
│           ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆   ┆ n/Manager ┆           ┆ ance      ┆          │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────────┘
```

And **print(df.head(3))**:

```
shape: (3, 32)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────────┐
│ Milestone ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ … ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ __UNNAMED ┆ __UNNAME │
│ Status    ┆ __1       ┆ __2       ┆ __3       ┆   ┆ __30      ┆ __31      ┆ __32      ┆ D__33    │
│ Report    ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ ---       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆   ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str      │
│ str       ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆          │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════════╡
│ Org/Subdi ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ … ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null     │
│ v:        ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆          │
│ [Company] ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆          │
│ Homes     ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆          │
│ Lare…     ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆          │
│ Show Paus ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ … ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      ┆ null     │
│ e/Hold    ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆          │
│ Days: Yes ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆   ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆          │
│ Subdivisi ┆ Job       ┆ Lot       ┆ Template  ┆ … ┆ Ready for ┆ Buyer Ori ┆ Orientati ┆ Buyer    │
│ on        ┆           ┆ Number    ┆           ┆   ┆ Orienatio ┆ entation  ┆ on Accept ┆ Closed   │
│           ┆           ┆           ┆           ┆   ┆ n/Manager ┆           ┆ ance      ┆          │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_excel.html suggests that you can pass additional input to the underlying reading engine via `read_options`. It doesn't say what those options are for `calamine` though. You can however guess that by stepping through the code and seeing where that value is ultimately passed. Then check Calamine's documentation on what valid inputs for that are.

Comment: Polars is using fastexcel: http://fastexcel.toucantoco.dev/fastexcel.html#ExcelReader.load_sheet_by_name - so it looks like you're wanting to pass `read_options={'header_row': 6}`?

Comment: Didn't think to check fastexcel - that did it! Thank you so much. Weird thing is I had to use read_options={'header_row': 5} despite when I open the xlsx the header row being on row 7.

Comment: If you can reproduce the behaviour using fastexcel directly - perhaps it's something that should be reported: https://github.com/ToucanToco/fastexcel/issues